# error TS2339: Property 'toHexString' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, github-actions

I meet the following error. It looks strange. Locally, it works without errors it occurs only on the GitHub ci actions container. And I do not know how to catch it. Strange is also that the method `toHexString` exists in ObjectId type. NestJS, and mongoose are used so there are many similar types for different reasons. But they all show that they have the method. It is the problem of typescript.

```bash
● Test suite failed to run

    src/features/branch-role/services/branch-role.service.ts:28:41 - error TS2339: Property 'toHexString' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'.

    28       roleDTO.branchId = role.branchId?.toHexString();
```

There is a description of the error. It looks logical but it does not reveal the problem.
tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it be a mismatch between the target JS version in your `tsconfig.json`? Please, check that this file is the same (i.e. check that you are not gitignoring it)

Comment: I use the same file tsconfig.json I think. I can not say exactly because it is used by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this same error. I'm not exactly sure what the issue is but it is related to the type definitions for the `bson` module not being properly resolved.
Manually installing it worked for me.

```
yarn add -D @types/bson
```

OR

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bson
```

Comment: Yes, It can be a problem. It was present in my project when VSCode automatically generated imports. Now I have corrected it to be imported from ```mongodb```

Comment: Yes, I have found one that I missed.